# TypeScript doesn't infer correct type

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, static-typing

For this piece:

```
Promise.resolve('kromid')
  .then(all(identity))
  .then(([a]) => a.splita);
```

TypeScript doesn't say anything about `a.splita`. I'm expecting it to fail with:

> Property 'splita' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean
>   'split'?

Here's the rest of the code:

```
function all<T1, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1]>;
function all<T1, T2, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>, a9: Res<Param, T9>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, Param>(a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>, a9: Res<Param, T9>, a10: Res<Param, T10>): (p: Param) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
function all<Param>(...values: Res<Param, any>[]): (p: Param) => Promise<any[]>;
function all<Param>(...values: Res<Param, any>[]): (p: Param) => Promise<any[]> {
  return param => Promise.all(values.map(obj => obj.apply ? obj(param) : obj));
}
type Res<I, O> = ((i: I) => O | Promise<O>) | O | Promise<O>


function identity<T>(a: T): T {
  return a;
}
```

Can you spot where the problem is?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with TypeScript 2.6.2, so what version are you using?

Comment: @cartant I didn't notice the negation in the sentence as well. The OP is expecting a compilation error which he does NOT observe. I too, am not seeing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me to the issue I didn't quite get. I did play with your code a bit more and here are my findings. Type inference does not work well with function composition in TypeScript:

```
function identity<T>(a: T): T { return a; }
function toString<T>(a: T): string { return JSON.stringify(a); }

Promise.resolve('kromid')
  .then(promiseValue => {
    const composedFn = all(identity, toString);
//        ^^^^^^^^^^
//        T type of `promiseValue` was not inferred properly,
//        and was replaces with `any`
    return composedFn(promiseValue);
  })
  .then(([identityResult, toStringResult]) => {

  })
```

Notice that type inference broke for a function `(T) => T` but worked for a non-generic return type function `(T) => string`. Down the road, `identityResult` is of type `any`, while `toStringResult` is of the right type `string`.

[image]

I think, the real root cause is covered in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10247). Sorry my answer is not very helpful. Type inference is the most complex topic for me, that's why I'm digging into your example.

## Scratching my old answer

#### Why is it happening?

I think, the key is in this line:

```
  .then(all(identity))
```

It is equivalent to

```
  .then(x => all(identity)(x))
```

rather than to

```
  .then(x => all(identity(x)))
```

The types will be inferred differently in two cases and I think you expect the latter interpretation of your code while getting the former.

#### How to achieve the error you expected to see

**Variant 1**: If you rewrite the code so that `all()` receives the `string` promise value and the `identity()` in the right order, you'll see the error.

```
Promise.resolve('kromid')
  .then(text => all(text)(identity))
  .then(([a]) => a.splita);
```

Resulting in:

> [ts] Property 'splita' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean 'split'?

[image]
[image]

**Variant 2**. Reorder the parameters of the overloaded `all()` function so that it enables using it in the way you want:

```
function all<T1, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>) => Promise<[T1]>;
function all<T1, T2, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>) => Promise<[T1, T2]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>, a9: Res<Param, T9>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9]>;
function all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, Param>(p: Param): (a1: Res<Param, T1>, a2: Res<Param, T2>, a3: Res<Param, T3>, a4: Res<Param, T4>, a5: Res<Param, T5>, a6: Res<Param, T6>, a7: Res<Param, T7>, a8: Res<Param, T8>, a9: Res<Param, T9>, a10: Res<Param, T10>) => Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10]>;
function all<Param>(p: Param): (...values: Res<Param, any>[]) => Promise<any[]>;

function all<Param>(p: Param): (...values: Res<Param, any>[]) => Promise<any[]> {
  return values => Promise.all(values.map((obj: any) => obj.apply ? obj(p) : obj));
}

type Res<I, O> = ((i: I) => O | Promise<O>) | O | Promise<O>;

function identity<T>(a: T): T {
  return a;
}

Promise.resolve('kromid')
  .then(all(identity))
  .then(([a]) => a.splita);
```

It will achieve the same result:

[image]

I hope, my answer is complete and correct now. :)

Comment: Oh, you have no idea how much i hoped for that too. But you might have missed from the types that I want the `all` function to be able to receive multiple arguments: `all(identity, identity..)`, hence the overload. Unfortunately reordering the types, introduces two problems: the [type from above](https://imgur.com/a/OScyf), and the [number of arguments](https://imgur.com/a/A9Kpg) in `all`.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, Igor!

Comment: @Birowsky now I think, we have an answer to `why` this is happening, but not how to overcome it. :/ I'll star this question in case you find a way to make TS infer the type.

Comment: And I'll upvote for the effort :} It's just too bad that we still don't have this functionality. It was gonna read like poetry, now it'll look like daily politics.

Comment: Well, the good news is, they are considering this as a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20861#issuecomment-353681912

Comment: @Birowsky Yes, I've dug to the same post on which you commented to yesterday. I didn't see your bug report though. But I think, my answer explains what you wanted to figure out (`Can you spot where the problem is?`) Now it's a matter of TypeScript contributors to fix that behavior.